# applying a function to graph data using mapReduceTriplets in spark and graphx

Tags: scala, network-programming, apache-spark, graph-algorithm, spark-graphx

I'm having some problems applying the mapReduceTriplets to my graph network in spark using graphx.

I've been following the tutorials and read in my own data which is put together as [Array[String],Int], so for example my vertices are:

`org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexRDD[Array[String]]` e.g. (3999,Array(17, Low, 9))

And my edges are:

`org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeRDD[Int]`
e.g. Edge(3999,4500,1)

I'm trying to apply an aggregate type function using mapReduceTriplets which counts how many of the last integer in the array of a vertices (in the above example 9) is the same or different to the first integer (in the above example 17) of all connected vertices.

So you would end up with a list of counts for the number of matches or non-matches.

The problem I am having is applying any function using mapReduceTriplets, I am quite new to scala so this may be really obvious, but in the graphx tutorials it has an example which is using a graph with the format Graph[Double, Int], however my graph is in the format of Graph[Array[String],Int], so i'm just trying as a first step to figure out how I can use my graph in the example and then work from there.

The example on the graphx website is as follows:

```
    val olderFollowers: VertexRDD[(Int, Double)] = graph.mapReduceTriplets[(Int, Double)](
  triplet => { // Map Function
    if (triplet.srcAttr > triplet.dstAttr) {
      // Send message to destination vertex containing counter and age
      Iterator((triplet.dstId, (1, triplet.srcAttr)))
    } else {
      // Don't send a message for this triplet
      Iterator.empty
    }
  },
  // Add counter and age
  (a, b) => (a._1 + b._1, a._2 + b._2) // Reduce Function
)
```

Any advice would be most appreciated, or if you think there is a better way than using mapreducetriplets I would be happy to hear it.

Edited new code

```
val nodes = (sc.textFile("C~nodeData.csv")
.map(line => line.split(",")).map( parts => (parts.head.toLong, parts.tail) ))

val edges = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc, "C:~edges.txt")


val graph = edges.outerJoinVertices(nodes) {
case (uid, deg, Some(attrList)) => attrList
case (uid, deg, None) => Array.empty[String]
}


val countsRdd = graph.collectNeighbors(EdgeDirection.Either).leftOuterJoin(graph.vertices).map {
  case (id, t) => {
    val neighbors: Array[(VertexId, Array[String])] = t._1
    val nodeAttr = (t._2)
    neighbors.map(_._2).count( x => x.apply(x.size - 1) == nodeAttr(0))

  }
}
```

Comment: What version of Spark? `mapReduceTriplets` has been replaced by `aggregateMessages` in the latest versions of Spark.

Comment: version 1.3.0, does aggregateMessages work in a similar manner?

Comment: Take a look at the transition guide: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#mrTripletsTransition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `GraphOps.collectNeighbors` instead of either `mapReduceTriplets` or `aggregateMessages`.

`collectNeighbors` will give you an RDD with, for every VertexId in your graph, the connected nodes as an array. Just reduce the Array based on your needs. Something like:

```
val countsRdd = graph.collectNeighbors(EdgeDirection.Either)
  .join(graph.vertices)
  .map{ case (vid,t) => {
    val neighbors = t._1
    val nodeAttr = t._2
    neighbors.map(_._2).filter( <add logic here> ).size
  }
```

If this doesn't get you going in the right direction, or you get stuck, let me know (the "" part, for example).

Comment: Thanks David, this looks really helpful, I'll have a play with it and let you know if I run into any problems.

Comment: If it works for you remember to come back and accept my answer and/or up vote it! :)

Comment: Thanks again for the help, although I'm having some problems with writing the logic argument and may be going down the wrong path. What i'm thinking (which I know to be wrong at the moment) is below, with x being the Array[String] taken from neighbours (so the info contained within the source node). I think it is just comparing arrays, rather than components within them, although I can't seem to access individual component elements? Might be completely wrong though...

neighbors.map(_._2).filter(x=> x== nodeAttr)

Comment: As you point out, you are trying to compare the whole array. For the logic you want you need to pick out the last value with something like `x.apply(x.size - 1) == nodeAttr(0)` That would compare the last element of `x` with the first element of `nodeAttr`

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion, I seem to keep coming up against a problem with nodeAttr(0) though, I get the error message Option[Array[String]] does not take parameters, for some reason I can't seem to access any individual components of the array.

Comment: I've added the code I'm currently using under edited new code above. I tried getting around the problem by creating a new value of nodeAttr.toString, taking the number from there and then putting that into the logic function, but I kept coming up with zero counts.

Comment: See my edits just now. Changed `RDD.leftOuterJoin` to `RDD.join`. Also, I changed `count` to `size`. Maybe this helps?